# Hunting for the Critic badge

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Some features on TeX.SX are time-dependent. For example, voting and comment editing. The bronze [critic badge](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/7/critic), however, does not fall under such time constraints. It is awarded immediately after you issue your

[image: Critic badge]

However, reversing this down vote (within the given time limit) does not reverse the awarded badge. Even the reputation loss from [down voting an answer/question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) on TeX.SX is recovered within the time limit.

Now, perhaps this post doesn't matter at all, since

1. It's just a bronze badge; who cares.
2. Everyone without this badge will try this down vote reversal to still "stay neutral/positive on their voting", but have a +1 in the badge department.

Both points, I guess, are valid, since some badges are awarded by default for just forming part of the TeX.SX community (like [posting your first question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/2/student), [answering your first question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/1/teacher), [up-voting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/6/supporter), etc). Also, even the bronze badge description states the obvious, and somewhat verifies point (1) above:

[image]

However, does this possible "loop hole" constitute "basic use of TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange"?

<sub>I mention/reference [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) intermittently since I presume this is common across all StackExchange sites. I may be wrong, since I didn't go hunting myself. :-/</sub>

Comment: See also this post on meta.SO: [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2137).

Comment: reminder: you need at least 125 rep to even cast a downvote. Also, it is not "immediate", it depends on the periodic badge schedule. A few minutes minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It by design, since awarded badges will not be removed, with rare exceptions. Hendrik's link to ["Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely) shows further explanation specifically for the Critic badge.

So once you earned the Critic badge by a downvote, it's intended to stay even if you reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it is intended, but why? And even in that case it could be changed:

> I know this badge is trivial, but so is making it work right, so why not do so? It appears 
>   that the application of this badge is currently controlled by a flag that gets set to true 
>   the first time a down vote button is clicked. It can never be set back to false even if the 
>   user immediately undoes their down vote.
>   Do away with this flag and have the code that checks for application of this badge examine 
>   the down vote count instead.
>   ([Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely/10574#10574))

Comment: It works rightly: if you made a down vote, you get it. How many badges do you know which can be removed by the user by reversing his action?

Comment: At least the badge should only be awarded after the 5min grace period, not before. This way at least the badge costs you 1rep.